# wxPython: how to get screen x/y for line in a RichTextCtrl?

Tags: wxpython

I want to pop up a window directly beneath the current line (the line with the insertion cursor) in a RichTextCtrl. Is there a way to get the screen coordinate of a specific character or line in the control? There doesn't seem to be, but that's such a glaring omission I figure I must be missing something.

I have lines of varying height so I can't just figure out the line, multiply by line height, and then figure out the offset from the top of the window. What are my options, or am I simply out of luck?

FWIW, I'm using python 2.5 and wxPython 2.8.9.1 (and no ability to upgrade at the moment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try to test with this function?

```
wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl.GetCaret().GetPosition()
```

when I just try that, Its return tuple with probably x, y locations of cursor, in pixel(probably)

Let me know if there is any issue with that.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. Combined with self.GetScreenPosition() and caret.GetSize() I'm able to compute the baseline of current line.